# How do I get the server template link in python? (Discord)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I am trying to add a */load* command that will send the server template link. Any idea on how I can do that? Thanks!

**Code Below**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIa5l.png

Comment: Please read the docs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of a guild's templates using `await guild.templates()`, [as stated in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=template#discord.Guild.templates).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to only send the code? Thanks!

Comment: As in the template link or just the template code, if that makes sense.

Comment: @AfterSpark Please read the docs, as provided in the answer.